# How do I modify an existing website without the original psds?

Tags: html

I am trying to remodel my website which someone else built for me, and based on what I've learned so far, the design was made in photoshop and then "sliced?" in to HTML and CSS. My question is, how am I supposed to add content or rearrange things if I don't have those photoshop documents?

Comment: Edit the HTML and CSS with a text editor.

Comment: Your first step should be to gain access to your website's server. If you can do that, you can begin to think about modifying your site.

Comment: This belongs on [webmasters.se].  If you don't have the original files and have a lot of slices (and rollovers) you have a _huge_ job ahead of you. You may be able to reassemble the images from the slices but if you're going to make significant changes you're better off starting over.

Comment: You could always hire someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know HTML and CSS you don't need the psd's, you can just directly edit the design by changing the html and css files.

Comment: this might help: http://learncss.tutsplus.com/